# Among other things

Tags: phrase-meaning

With Turkish delight, chocolate milk and a false promise, a witch was able to have Edmund betray his own family. (This happened in a book)

Is the following sentence in this context correct?

‘With, among other things, Turkish delight, the witch was able to have Edmund betray his family.’

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work.

Comment: Grammatically correct, but sounds a bit awkward since the clause before "among other things" is only the word "with."

Comment: Why not just say *'with Turkish delight, among other things, the witch was able to have Edmund betray his family'*?